# Is it safe to read() from a file as soon as write() returns?

Tags: c, linux

I have a very specific application where I need an auto-increment variable with persistent storage.

To be precise, I store the decimal representation of an `int` variable on a file. To generate the next number, I `read()` from the file, convert the contents back to `int`, add 1 and `write()` back to the file. I do NOT need concurrent access to this data. Only one thread from one process calls the functions to retrieve the auto-increment number. The program runs on an embedded environment, where no-one will have access to the console, so security should not be a concern. If it matters, it runs on Linux 2.6.24 on MIPS.

The problem is, I am not getting 100% reproducible results. Sometimes I get repeated numbers, which is unacceptable for my application.

My implementation is as follows.

On starting the application, I have:

```
int fd = open("myfile", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_SYNC, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);
```

And the auto-increment functions:

```
int get_current(int fd)
{
    char value[SIZE];
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    read(fd, value, SIZE);
    return atoi(value);
}

int get_next(int fd)
{
    char value[SIZE];
    int cur = get_current(fd);
    memset(value, 0, SIZE);
    sprintf(value, "%d", cur + 1);
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    write(fd, value, SIZE);
    //fsync(fd);  /* Could inserting this be the solution? */
    return (cur + 1);
}
```

I have intentionally left out error checking above for the sake of code readability. I have code in place to check return values of all syscalls.

The code was originally written by another person, and now that I have detected this problem, the first step to solve it is to find out what could have caused it. I am concerned that it could be related to the way file accesses are cached. I know when I `write()` I have no gurantee the data ever actually reached the physical medium, but is it safe to call `read()` without having called `fsync()` and still get predictable results? If it is, then I'm out of ideas ;)

Thanks for reading through.

Comment: Note that data files should not be executable.  Publicly writable files fill me with concern - but can occasionally be necessary.  However, you have to be aware that anyone can write anything into the file at any time - alphabetic characters, punctuation, gibberish, nothing.  Granted, it likely requires malice to do that, but don't underestimate the ability of fools to break your system.  You might be better off with a daemon-like process that doles out the numbers, recording the last issued number in a file that only it (the daemon, and the daemon's owner) can write to.

Comment: Debugging idea...add a log file opened with O_APPEND.  Format a second buffer which contains a newline and maybe identifying information (TID, PID, sub-second time), and arrange for the code to write to that file too.  You should then be able to see when the reads don't match with the writes - unless the extra write converts the bug into a Heisenbug and suppresses the problem.  (Is there any chance that there are multiple file descriptors all referring to the same file?)

Comment: Is `get_current()` file static?  Is the only call to it the call in `get_next()`?  If not, where else is it used and why?

Comment: @Leffler: What do you mean by file static? `get_current` is called from at least one other place to query how many number have been generated, but why would that matter?

Comment: @David: 'file static' is 'static', but emphasizing that it is only accessible from within a single source file.  One way you could run into problems is if the code that calls get_current() then uses that value as if it had come from `get_next()`.  Since you're dealing with a single process, and the multi-threading is apparently kept away from `get_next()`, then can the problem be that `get_current()` is used where `get_next()` should be used?  It is clutching at straws.  You might also want to look at the [MTD FAQ](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/faq/general.html) too.

Comment: @Leffler: Great article (MTD FAQ)! I happen to have JFFS2 file system, and the section "How do I ensure that data is written to flash?" on http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/faq/jffs2.html was really insightful. Thank you once again for your invaluable help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to read immediately after writing.  In a Unix-like system, the data is safely in the kernel buffer pool when a `write()` returns and will be returned to other processes that need to read the data.  Similar comments apply when using O_SYNC, O_DSYNC, O_FSYNC (which ensure that data is written to disk) and to Windows systems.  Clearly, an asynchronous write will not be complete when the `aio_write()` call returns, but it will be complete when the completion is signalled.

However, your problem arises because you are not ensuring that you have a single process or thread accessing the file at a time.  You *must* ensure that you get serial access so that you don't get two processes (or threads) reading from the file at the same time.  This is the 'lost update' problem in DBMS terms.

You need to ensure that only one process has access at a time.  If your processes cooperate, you can use advisory locking (via `fcntl()` on POSIX systems).  If your processes don't cooperate, or you're not sure, you may need to go for mandatory locking, or use some other technique altogether.

Comment: I was afraid of that answer.. If it is indeed safe to `read()` immediately after `write()` then what could be causing the problem I encountered? My process does not have any other thread accessing that same file, nor is there any other process doing so. Perhaps I should have mentioned before, I am running on Linux 2.6.24 on MIPS and the physical medium is a Memory Technology Device (mtdblock).

Comment: POSIX intentionally omits mandatory locking, and good systems do not allow it because it's dangerous and generally Considered Harmful(tm).

Comment: @R..: In what way is mandatory locking Considered Harmful™?  The main concern is that it tends to inhibit concurrency, but superficially, that seems to be what is needed here.  (I'm about to address David's comments that he is not dealing with multiple threads or multiple processes.  I'm just not quite sure how, yet.)

Comment: For the same reason Windows users hate when they get errors like "Cannot delete foo: File is in use by another program" or whatever.

Comment: @David: In theory, the kernel should be shielding you from thedevice specifics - that is its job.  I found this [article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1187102&seqNum=6) about MTD systems.  I assume that no other process (or thread within your process) could be accessing the `/dev/mtd/X` device while this one is accessing the `/dev/mtdblock/X` device?  Is your process multi-threaded?  Are you sure that no other thread is getting the 'next number'?

Comment: @R..: Right-that's why you don't use it unless you're forced to.  This might, or might not, be one of the occasions where it is necessary.  You struggle mightily to avoid it, but when it is necessary, it is better than uncontrolled updates.

Comment: @Leffler: I appreciate the article you pointed me to, even though I don't think it helps solve the issue at hand.. But I got to learn a few things about MTD, so thanks! I am positive no other thread is accessing these functions. Portions of the code are multi-threaded, but the auto-increment functions are only called from the main thread.

Comment: @David: if threads are involved at all, I suspect you're wrong and that the function is somehow getting called from another thread. One easy way to test would be to wrap the function with something like `assert(pthread_mutex_trylock(&lock)==0);` and `pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);` Note the assert form - this way your program will crash rather than just waiting when concurrent access is attempted so you can track down what's happening. Or just use `pthread_mutex_lock` if you don't care that it's being called from multiple threads.

Comment: Any chance a second copy of the program has accidentally gotten started?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you `write()` to a file and then `read()` from it you should see the data you just wrote. The exception is if another process or thread has overwritten the file in the meantime, or if the write() actually failed.

Answer (score 0):

The content of a file is a really bad way to implement an atomic counter. How big will your count get? If it's not huge, one simple method would be to write a single byte (doesn't matter what) to increment the counter, and use `fstat` (`st_size`) to read the counter. `ftrunc` can reset the counter to zero.

A cleaner way to implement what you want would be to memory-map the file (with `mmap`) and store not just the count but also a `pthread_mutex_t` that's initialized to be process-shared, and lock it when updating the count.

Another way you could use `mmap` is if you have C1x atomic types (`_Atomic int`) but you'll have to wait 5-10 years. :-) Or you could use gcc intrinsics or asm for atomic operations. This solution has by far the best performance (mildly better than the `pthread_mutex_t` approach, and hundreds of times faster than the `write` approach).

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but my application does not have to deal with concurrent access or any of the complications it brings. I just have to stamp every line of output from my program with a unique sequential number. This does, however, mean that the counter could get pretty big. I'll update my question to make this clear.

Comment: If it's only a single program, why do you store the counter in a file and not just a global variable? If the value is kept and used across multiple runs of the program, what are you doing to ensure that more than one instance of the program is not run at the same time?

Comment: It is an embedded system. The application running is started on boot and handles every aspect of interaction with the user. I need to store the value in a file because I need the variable to start from the last generated number when the device reboots.

Comment: @David, Use a global. Checkpoint the count in the file on every write (less often if you can trap failure and checkpoint then), and read the file only once at start up to set the initial value of the count in a global.

Comment: @RBerteig: That does seem like a more elegant solution. But I just don't feel confident it would solve the problem I find myself with. If only I could identify what was causing it, then I could safely look for alternatives, like the one you proposed. Thanks!

Comment: @David, my proposal is to only read the value from the file once, before the process ever writes the file. Ideally, you could open the file for read, close it once you've read the value, and open it separately for write. If that isn't reliable, then you have bigger problems. I'd also include some kind of check-digit or perhaps a true checksum so that at startup you can tell if the last value was completely written or not. How you handle the failure is another question. One way is to alternate between two offsets in the file on each write, including a separate checksum in each.

Comment: @RBerteig: OP obviously has concurrent access from multiple threads/processes going on that he's not aware about, and your suggestion will only bury the bug (race conditions with file access are much more likely to be caught because they window of time is 1000 times larger than variable access, but if the race remains, it will eventually happen again...)

Comment: @RBerteig: "If that isn't reliable, then you have bigger problems." lol. I like your idea, thanks again for taking the time to reply!

Comment: Rather than checksums, just write the value twice in a row. If the two copies aren't identical, you detect a failed/partial write with 100% accuracy rather than whatever statistical accuracy the checksum gives you.

Comment: @R, you're right that the underlying issue is likely unexpected concurrency.

Comment: @R.., @RBerteig: Just as a follow-up, I think I found a suitable explanation for my problem. I found out about the problem by analyzing the list of generated numbers on one particular device that had been running untethered - not under debugging - for a few days. Since the operator could remove power from the device at any time, I'm guessing the problem occured because even though `read()` immediately after `write()` does work, when power was cut the new number never made it to permanent storage. The only way to make sure (to an extent) it did would have required a call to `fsync()`. continues

Comment: (continued) Anyway, I have spent the last two days implementing a much better solution that won't be suceptible to things like this. Thank you both!

Comment: Glad to see I was proven wrong. :-) What solution did you end up using?