# thread safety of read/pread system calls 

Tags: c, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety

I have few queries related to read()/pread() system calls in a multithreaded environment

I am using Mac-OSX which is freeBsd based , if that helps in any way
I am only using this file in read mode,and not read/write
And the language is c/c++

Suppose we have a file on disk
AAAABBBBCCCCDDDEEEE....

and 4 alphabets fit on one page of the file

So Page1:AAAA

Page2:BBBB
..... and so on

now i initiate a read system call from two different threads with the same file descriptor
my intension is to read first page from thread 1, second page from thread 2,..and so on.

read(fd,buff,sizeof(page));

From the man page i am given to understand that read will also increment the file pointer ,so definitely i am gonna get garbled responses like

ABCC ABBB ..  etc (with no particular sequence )

to remedy this i can use pread()

"Pread() performs the same function, but reads from the speci-
     fied position in the file without modifying the file pointer" // from man pages

But i am not sure whether using pread will actually help me in my objective , cause even though it does not increment the internal file pointer , there are no guarantees that the responses are not jumbled.

All of my data is page aligned and i want to read one page from each thread like

Thread 1 reads:AAAA
Thread 2 reads:BBBB
Thread 3 reads:CCCC ... without actually garbling the content ..

I also found a post [Is it safe to read() from a file as soon as write() returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486563/is-it-safe-to-read-from-a-file-as-soon-as-write-returns)

but it wasnt quite useful .

I am also not sure whether read() will actually have the problem, that i am thinking of.The file that i am reading is a binary file and hence i litle difficult to just quickly manually read and verify..

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`read` and `write` change the position of the underlying open file. They are "thread safe" in the sense that your program will not have undefined behavior (crash or worse) if multiple threads perform IO on the same open file at once using them, but the order and atomicity of the operations could vary depending on the type of file and the implementation.

On the other hand, `pread` and `pwrite` do not change the position in the open file. They were added to POSIX for exactly the purpose you want: performing IO operations on the same open file from multiple threads or processes without the operations interfering with one another's position. You could still run into some trouble with ordering if you're mixing `pread` and `pwrite` (or multiple calls to `pwrite`) with overlapping parts of the file, but as long as you avoid that, they're perfectly safe for what you want to do.

Comment: And this: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_07 (XSH 2.9.7 Thread Interactions with Regular File Operations).

Answer (score 1):

`fcntl` advisory locks are locks on a *range* of the file.  You may find this useful to serialize reads and writes to the same region while allowing concurrency on separate regions.

```
int rc;
struct flock f;
f.l_type = F_RDLCK;  /* or F_WRLCK */
f.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
f.l_start = n;
f.l_len = 1;
while ((rc = fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &f)) == -1 && errno = EINTR)
    ;
if (rc == -1)
    perror("fcntl(F_SETLKW)");
else {
    /* do stuff */
    f.l_type = F_UNLCK;
    fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &f);
}
```

Multiple reader locks are permitted at a time, while a single writer lock blocks all others.

Be warned that [all file locking mechanisms are subtly broken on some configurations on all platforms](http://apenwarr.ca/log/?m=201012#13).

Comment: Be warned that a lot of file locking does not work between threads, only processes. I don't remember about fcntl but don't trust it. Test it.

Comment: fcntl is in fact locking between processes.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl

If you are using pthread, the library provides pthread_rwlock_* functions that implement per thread read/write locking. It does not provide range locking though, you'll have to write your own...

Answer (score -1):

Share a mutex lock between the two threads, enable the lock in the thread before it reads, and unlock the lock when the correct read is complete. See `pthread_mutex_create`, `pthread_mutex_lock`, and `pthread_mutex_unlock`.

Comment: Thats a remedy but it will restrict I/O to just one thread , i dont want to do that as i am only interested in reading ,and not read-write

Comment: I don't think you do it without blocking one thread on the I/O. Also, if you only block during the simple read, and not the entire execution of the thread, the wait should be minimal. The only other alternative is to have each thread open the file with its own file descriptor, but you'll have to know what each is reading in order to ignore that information. This will also slow the threads as there will be twice as much I/O.

Comment: This is unnecessary and not the answer to OP's question. The whole point of `pread` is to do what OP wants, and the answer is that yes it's safe.

Comment: I was unaware of those functions. I guess I have never had this sort of need. Learn something new everyday. The only downside, you still have to be aware of what the other thread(s) are processing so you don't double up.