# Atomicity of UNIX read()/write() when sending data to device

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, unix, parallel-processing

When writing directly to a device in /dev, I open a file descriptor and perform a UNIX write() followed by a read().  Can I have multiple threads doing this write()/read() sequence on the *same* file descriptor, and not get jumbled data if two threads enter the write() function at the same time?

References to std documentation would be immensely helpful.  I've not been able to find anything though.  Someone has mentioned that such operations are atomic in the kernel, but I am sceptical.

Also, to clarify this is a file in /dev, so any insight as to how far the "file pointer" concept applies here is helpful as well.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5268307/315052) is related to yours.

Comment: Yes, I understand that doing this on a regular file changes the file pointer and that can mix things up.  This isn't a file though, it is a device in /dev.

Comment: The device driver itself would have to make sure that state is maintained consistently if entered by multiple threads. That's what the file system `read`/`write` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File pointers (`FILE *fp`, for example), are a layer in the user-side code sitting above the function calls (such as `write()`).  Access to `fp` is controlled by locks in a threaded environment (you can't have to threads modifying the same structure at the same time).

Inside the kernel, I'd expect there to be a lock on the file descriptor (and/or 'open file description') to prevent it being used from two threads at once.

You can look up the POSIX specification for [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) and 
[`getchar_unlocked()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getchar_unlocked.html)
to find out more about locking etc — at least for a POSIX compliant implementation.

Note that POSIX still uses C99.  Therefore, it is not cognizant of the C11 thread facilities.  The C11 standard does not have `read()` et al (file I/O using file descriptors), so it says nothing about such system calls.  Neither does it provide a `getchar_unlocked()` or any of its relatives.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I have not been in kernels for awhile, but this is the way it used to work.

**For disk files:**
Can you open the file in append mode, writing block sizes `<= BLKSIZE` ?

Small enough block sizes guarantee, in POSIX environments, atomic writes in POSIX environments (actually, the limit may be greater than BLKSIZE... I'm too lazy to hunt around for the alternate symbol).

Append guarantees seeks to the end of the file... for devices supporting seeks. Combine with atomic writes you should be golden.

Each buffer must stand by itself under the assumption some "foreign" information may follow it.

**For ttys:**
Append mode makes no sense here. As before, but paying attention to line endings gets even more important. And this very much does not apply to reads. Codes ttys treat as control sequences can also trip you up if even the modes the sequences enable split across blocks.

**For other devices:**
Can get tricky here. Depends on the device.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you are referring to a generic character device (e.g. a tty) since you were not specific. As far as I know, each fd-type operation (e.g. read()/write()) maps directly into a call into the driver.

Therefore, the driver will receive each write()'s data chunk as a whole and not see the next one's data until it is done (e.g. data is queued to be transmitted).

However, if the driver does not consume the entire chunk of data at once (i.e. write() returns less than the specified number of bytes, then there is no guarantee, that the thread will be able to write again with the remainder before another thread does a different write().

Also, as Johnathan Leffler noted, if you use standard I/O with process-level buffering, all bets are off.

Bottom line, if you are using direct fd writes, each write will map directly to one driver function call. From there, it's up to the driver as to if write is atomic.

**Edit:** wlformyd brings up the question of locking between multiple threads on multiple processors. To my knowledge, there is no locking on a FD and, in fact, that would be ineffective as multiple FDs could be used to access the same device.

I believe it is up to the driver itself to do locking to prevent contention to internal queues and/or hardware. in that sense, on a multi-processor system, the kernel doesn't prevent multiple simultaneous access to a driver's write routine. However, a properly written driver should do the locking to prevent mixing of output between two write calls.

Comment: So, when in sys_write calls the write function of the driver, it is locking on the file descriptor and so this part of the op is atomic.  Correct?